# I can’t remember the name of that component

Tags: relay, identification, components, photosensor

I’m looking for the name of the component that act like a relay but instead of using a coil to generate a magnetic field that moves the relay « arm » it uses a LED and a photosensor.

It allows to isolate a high voltage of a circuit from a low voltage.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I think you're looking for an opto-isolator (aka optocoupler).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Optocoupler, optoisolator, solid state relay, opto-triac.

Comment: Optocoupler! That’s what I was looking for ! Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1):

Solid-state relay is the term you are looking for for high power devices.

Opto-isolator for small currents.

Comment: A solid-state relay is just an optocoupler with aspirations.